# Excel measuring arithmetical average (counting blank cells)

Tags: excel

I have a problem in Excel. I'm making a program to monitor the consumption of fuel per month. As I do not tank fuel every day, but only every couple days I'd like the program to measure aritchmetic mean for me.

This means it would take the last input and count all blank cells above (excluding my previous input) and measure the mean of fuel consumption in these days.

Example of how it should work:

[link to image] http://i64.tinypic.com/2dre87m.jpg

Edit: If anybody knows how to count number of empty cells between 2 inputs it would also suffice to me.

Comment: This is not a programming-related question. This should go to super user

Comment: @balping: spreadsheet development *is* a type of programming: http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/SpreadsheetProgramming_ECSE09.pdf

Comment: FWIW, Excel has an `ISBLANK` function you can use to check if a cell is blank.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your desired results using an array formula. Assuming your headings Day,Fuel, and Average are in cells A1, B1, and C1 respectively; copy and paste the following formula in cell C2 hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and drag the formula down your column.

```
=IFERROR(IF(B2="","",(B2/(LARGE(IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:B2,$B$2:B2,0),""),1)-LARGE(IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:B2,$B$2:B2,0),""),2)))),B2)
```

It gave me a "formula omits adjacent cells" error, but we want to omit the cells below the target row on purpose, so just ignore the error. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as charm. I've been trying all night long, but I was able only to output the consumption and not the average per day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(B2="","",ABS(B2/(MATCH(0,B$2:B2,-1)-SUM(MATCH(0,B1:B$2,-1)))))
```

in C2 and copy down.

if cells in column B can contain string values then you can use this formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2),ABS(B2/(MATCH(0,B$2:B2,-1)-SUM(MATCH(0,B1:B$2,-1)))),"")
```